# Dependency Graph plugin jenkins doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I've installed Graphviz and necessary plugins for Jenkins to run Dependency graph plugin, but when I click on Dependency Graph, it doesn't show me anything, I don't know where is the problem, my Jenkins is v2.32.1, thank you very much

[image: ERROR GRAPH]

Comment: Can you right-click the image and check the source, or better, see what happens if you browse that url

Comment: <img src="graph.png" lazymap="graph.map"> == $0, any idea?

Comment: what happens when you open it in a new window? do you get a 404? 500? Anything in the jenkins logs

Answer (score 2):

In my case I hadn't graphviz in my system.

I solve my issue running the following command (ubuntu 16.04.03):

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

No reboot was required on jenkins and than the dependency graph worked as expected.